# I need to hide a div using css which is duplicate in a div

Tags: html, css

I don't have access to html code and I only need to hide a div using CSS which is duplicated in same place.

Here is the HTML code and I need to hid div containing class "term"

```html
<div class="main">
 <div>
  <div class="term">some text</div>
  <div class="term">some text</div>
  <div class="term">some text</div>
  <div class="taxonomy">some text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to hide all of the class if there are duplicates, or show one and hide the rest?

Comment: show 1 and hide the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.term {
  display: none;
}

.main > div > div:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="term">some text 1</div>
    <div class="term">some text 2</div>
    <div class="term">some text 3</div>
    <div class="taxonomy">some text 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it is showing blank space when it hide the other divs

Comment: OK, give me a sec

Comment: i don't know here is also 1 downvote for question, don't know why people don't respect others.

Comment: They just misuse of their power. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143041/discussion-between-imran-saeed-and-mayersdesign).

Comment: I don't need that space, I want to hide others only show first but no space

Comment: It didn't helped.